# sed mac add text to specific line with double quotes

Tags: sed, macintosh

I'm trying to use this as my starting guide for using sed to add a line to a file in OSX. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631989/sed-insert-line-command-osx

```
sed -i '.json' '2i\
this is a test place
    ' dummy.txt
```

The above works. But I need to do expansion so I'm starting with something simple by just replacing with double quotes like

```
sed -i '.json' "2i\
this is a test place
    " dummy.txt
```

Why do I get `command i expects \ followed by text`? Or how do I use double quotes on Mac to add text to a specific line?

Comment: @steeldriver can you put that as the answer so i can mark it as answered. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed "2i\\
These are words on\\
multiple lines\\
" input
1
These are words on
multiple lines
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

You need to escape the backslash so that `sed` gets to parse it and escape the literal linefeed you're trying to escape for `sed` rather than the shell.

```
$ sed '2i\
thing' input
```

With the strong quotes, everything is passed literally, so `sed` sees `<2> <i> <literal linefeed>`

```
$ sed "2i\
thing" input
```

With the weak quotes, the shell gets first dibs at parsing the string, and  so `sed` sees `<2> <i> <linefeed>`, which is a syntax error.